# Application of Newton-Raphson method

Tags: numerical-methods

Is Newton-Raphson method applicable to solve rational equations? or any equation except polynomial equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's Method is applicable for real-valued functions. However, it does not work all the time. There are many possible reasons for Newton's Method to fail such as  if the derivative doesn't exist at the root.